# Can not get second table value in inner join in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working in CakePHP framework. I want to join two tables. So I have written query like below.

```
$details=$this->Deal->find('all',array('joins'=>array(
                          array(
                           'table'=>'merchants',
                           'alias'=>'Merchant',
                           'fields' => array('Merchant.username'),
                           'conditions' =>array('Merchant.id=Deal.merchant_id')
                          )
                        ),'conditions'=>array('Deal.id'=>$id)));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($details);
```

When I print the details, then it will give only **deal** table record. Here I also want **Merchant.username**.

So what would I have to change in the above query?

**Note :-** I am working with CakePHP version 1.3.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$details = $this->Deal->find('all', array('joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'merchants',
            'alias' => 'Merchant',
            'conditions' => array('Merchant.id=Deal.merchant_id')
        )
    ), 'conditions' => array('Deal.id' => $id),
    'fields' => array('Merchant.username', 'Deal.*'),
        )
);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($details);
```

Comment: Great its working. So I have to write **Deal.*** in fields.

Comment: if you want whole values.

Comment: Please make answer not just code only, explain at least with a short sentence how your code solves the issue!